# is kernel singleton, can I create it whenever needed

Tags: c#, ninject

I am trying to use Ninject for the first time, and I am not sure how to use it.
Lets say that I am not using injection (constructor or method), can I freely do;

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
var types = kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IDomainEventHandler<T>))
.GetImplementingTypes();
```

or is there a specific way of accessing the kernel? When `new StandardKernel()` am I creating a new kernel, or is it just a wrapper class?

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `new StandardKernel()` it always creates a new instance of `StandardKernel`. If it would be a singleton, the constructor would not be exposed.

If you want to use Ninject as service locator (*does not matter how much I do not recommend to do so*) you have to pass that instance to dependent code. Or simply expose it as some `public static` property and init in e.g. on app startup.

With `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator` you can also use it this way:

**Registration**

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
IServiceLocator ninjectServiceLocator = new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel);
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => ninjectServiceLocator);
```

**Usage**

```
var service = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMyService>();
```

Or in ASP web application you can acces it like:

```
var kernel = ((NinjectHttpApplication) HttpContext.ApplicationInstance).Kernel;
var service = kernel.Get<IService>();
```

*But as I said. These approaches are not genarally recommended. Ninject is not intended to be used this way. You should better try DI with constructor injection.*

Comment: This is a scenario where I am trying to implement domain events with just the interface definition, I was doing this already with Reflection beforehand. So, is this possible with a constructor (preferrabbly method) injection? And also, I would not really want to bind the interfaces to  concrete classes but rather prefer the DI toolkit to scan through my assemblies for the implementing classes.